# Countdown timer does not stop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

If an answer is given before 10 seconds, I need a stop function. I've tried some ideas but can't find a solution

Here's the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elturko/j7nFu/5/) and my code. Can anyone help, please?

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="timer" width="48" height="48"></canvas>
<span id="num"></span>

<br /><br />
<a href="javascript:istop();">stop</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function sCounter(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('timer');
    num = document.getElementById('num');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    fps= 40;

    var total = fps*10; //*second
    for(var i=total;i>=0;i--) {
        var delayed = (function(){
            var step = 1-i/total;
            var left = Math.ceil(i/fps);
            return function() {
                num.innerHTML=left;
                draw_next(step);

                if(left===0){  //if 0
                    //etc...
                }
            };
        })();
        var timer = setTimeout(delayed,-1000/fps*(i-total));
    }
}

function draw_next(step) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,48,48);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(24,24,20,Math.PI * (-0.5 + 0),Math.PI * (-0.5 + step*2),false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#dedede";
    ctx.stroke();
}

function istop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var timer = null;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    return false;
}

sCounter();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting the timer var on a common scope, seems too that the for loop is activating timers without the previous one has ended, because of that you can't clear them, see de fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQJkz/

```
    var timer = null

    function sCounter() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('timer');
    num = document.getElementById('num');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    fps = 40;

    var total = fps * 10; //*second

    var render = function (left, step, i) {
        num.innerHTML = left;
        draw_next(step);
        if (left)
        if (left === 0) { //if 0
            //etc...
        } else {
            delayed(i - 1);
        }
    };

    var delayed = function (i) {
        var step = 1 - i / total;
        var left = Math.ceil(i / fps);
        var current = function () {
            console.log(left, step);
            render(left, step, i);
        };
        timer = setTimeout(current, -1000 / fps * (i - total));
    }

    delayed(total - 1);
}
```

And it seems that you where trying to clear the timer after losing it's value. I had to change the istop scope to window because fiddle didn't find it. This should do the trick:

```
window.istop = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ok, it's overwritting the timers, you should only launch a setTimeout when the last one was done.

Comment: doing a for() you are calling for 40 timers. The best way is to fire the next timer when the current one was fired.

Comment: excuse me, if posible on jsFiddle edit for me, my code experience not enough for edit script. thnx for all answer.

Comment: I must end something before. Can you wait 5 hours?

Comment: I'm so sorry i forgot about this, i have made a fork on the fiddle, this version stops successfully but you will have to fix the timing.

Comment: The fiddle version is working at least for me. Did you tried?

Comment: sorry 3 days i was in the hospital. sorry. this code stop button work but timer doesn't work. i m not pro coder. i find near code https://gist.github.com/lagrz/891501  in this page. but this too so complicated. i need simple and stable code. :(

Comment: i think fix this second and use your code. for all helping thank u so so much.

Comment: Nothing, glad to help and hope everything goes ok :)